# Curve length in the Sasaki metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sasaki-metric

I am trying to read Appendix II.A.2 (Distances in the tangent bundle) in Canary, Epstein, Marden (eds.), Fundamentals of Hyperbolic Manifolds: Selected Expositions and am stumbling over a calculation of curve length in the Sasaki metric on the tangent bundle $TM$ of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. The actual question raised by this is more generic, though, and applies to any Riemannian manifold.

Specifically, it appears that the proof of Lemma II.A.2.4 (Lipschitz constant) is using the following inequality to estimate the vertical part of the curve length integral on $TM$ (after squaring, using a constant speed re-parametrization and Jensen's inequality):

$$\int\limits_0^1 \lVert\nabla_{\dot\alpha(s)}X(\alpha(s))\rVert^2_{\alpha(s)}\ ds \geq \lVert\tau_\alpha X(\alpha(0))-X(\alpha(1))\rVert^2_{\alpha(1)}$$

<s>with equality if $\alpha$ is a minimizing geodesic segment that lies inside a strongly convex set</s> [EDIT: see comments].
Here, $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection, $\alpha\colon[0,1]\rightarrow M$ is a curve, $X\in\Gamma(TM)$ is a vector field, $\lVert.\rVert_{\alpha(s)}$ denotes the norm in $T_{\alpha(s)}M$ induced by $g$ and $\tau_\alpha$ is parallel transport along $\alpha$.

I have not been able to prove the inequality for general curves nor the equality for minimizing geodesic segments. I could also not find this or a sufficient clue anywhere. I have looked in the original Sasaki paper, the papers by Gudmundsson/Kappos, Musso/Teicerri, and the books by do Carmo, Klingenberg, Lee, Michor and Petersen.

The right-hand side is clearly the squared length of a straight line in $T_{\alpha(1)}M$ and that is a minimizing geodesic segment in the Sasaki metric on $TM$ and of course also in the metric on $T_{\alpha(1)}M$ induced by $g$. When I try to rewrite the left-hand side as a (squared) length integral for a curve with the same end points (thus proving the inequality), I run into the question whether

$$\nabla_{\dot\alpha(s)}X(\alpha(s))=\frac{d}{ds}\left(\tau_\alpha^{s,1}X(\alpha(s))\right) \quad\text{ or possibly}\quad \tau_\alpha^{s,1}\nabla_{\dot\alpha(s)}X(\alpha(s))=\frac{d}{ds}\left(\tau_\alpha^{s,1}X(\alpha(s))\right)$$

(using that parallel transport is an isometry for the latter)? Is either one of these true or even sensible (and why)?
<s>This approach doesn't seem to help with the special case of equality if $\alpha$ is a minimizing geodesic segment that lies inside a strongly convex set, however. Not sure which of these conditions are strictly needed for equality to hold</s> [EDIT: see comments]. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why equality has to hold. Consider the simple example where $M = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\alpha$ the unit speed geodesic from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$. If you let $X(x,y) = (x^2,0)$, you have $\nabla_{\dot{\alpha}} X = (2x,0)$ and so its $\alpha(s)$ norm is equal to $2|x|$. The LHS integrates to $\frac43$ and the RHS is equal to $1$.

Comment: For the inequality, note that both sides of the integral is invariant if you replace $X$ by $X + Y$ where $Y$ is parallel-transported along $\alpha$. So you can subtract the parallel transport of $X(\alpha(0))$ from both side. Then the inequality follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus + Holder's inequality.

Comment: Thanks @WillieWong for the nice counterexample. It helped me understand that I was looking at that part of the proof in Canary/Epstein/Marden wrongly. I have edited the question accordingly, removing the part about equality.

Comment: @WillieWong: would you mind expanding your other comment into an answer so I can accept it? I get the idea about adding a parallel vector field but fail to see how Holder can be applied. The only way I know to get to an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus is via the equation $\frac{d}{dt} g(X,X) = 2g(\nabla_{\dot\alpha}X,X)$ but then I am stuck.

Comment: Done. (It is basically just a bunch of tricks using Cauchy-Schwarz / Holder.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inequality: first note that if $Y$ is a vector field parallel along $\alpha$, then
$$ \tau_\alpha (X + Y)(\alpha(0)) - (X+Y)(\alpha(1)) = \tau_\alpha X(\alpha(0)) - X(\alpha(1)) $$
and
$$ \nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} (X+Y)(\alpha(s)) = \nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} X(\alpha(s)). $$
So by adding a parallel transport of $X(\alpha(0))$, we can reduce to the case where $X(\alpha(0)) = 0$. It then suffices to prove:

> If $X(\alpha(0)) = 0$, then $\|X(\alpha(1))\|^2 \leq \int_0^1 \|\nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} X(\alpha(s)) \|^2_{\alpha(s)} ~ds$.

In the course of the proof below we will actually prove something stronger.

Consider the scalar function $s \mapsto \|X(\alpha(s))\|_{\alpha(s)} = \sqrt{g_{\alpha(s)}(X(\alpha(s)),X(\alpha(s)))}$. A direct computation shows that (using the metric compatibility of the Levi-Civita connection)

$$ \frac{d}{ds} \|X(\alpha(s))\|_{\alpha(s)} = \frac{1}{\|X(\alpha(s))\|_{\alpha(s)}} g_{\alpha(s)}( X(\alpha(s)), \nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} X(\alpha(s))) $$

By Cauchy-Schwarz on the inner product $g_{\alpha(s)}$ you find

$$ \frac{d}{ds} \|X(\alpha(s))\|_{\alpha(s)} \leq \| \nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} X(\alpha(s)) \|_{\alpha(s)} $$

Integrating both sides we find

$$ \|X(\alpha(1))\|_{\alpha(1)} \leq \int_0^1 \| \nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} X(\alpha(s)) \|_{\alpha(s)} ~ds $$

This is a stronger result than what you aimed for, as by Holder's inequality (I guess in this case you can also use Cauchy-Schwarz) you can write

$$ \int_0^1 \| \nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} X(\alpha(s)) \|_{\alpha(s)} ~ds = \int_0^1 \| \nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} X(\alpha(s)) \|_{\alpha(s)} \cdot 1 ~ds \leq \left( \int_0^1 \| \nabla_{\dot{\alpha}(s)} X(\alpha(s)) \|_{\alpha(s)}^2 ~ds\right)^{\frac12} \left( \int_0^1 1 ~ds\right)^{\frac12} $$

The final factor equals 1.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the Cauchy-Schwarz trick!